# Referencing previous element of a list in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, moving-average

I'm trying to learn python by implementing a very simple moving average crossover.

Below is my code:

```
px = [] ## list with prices
ma = [] ## list with corresponding 5-d MA 
position = []

for n, m in zip(px, ma):
    if n > m:
        position.append("1") ## signal for long position
    elif m > n:
        position.append("0") ## signal to close position

long_position = []

for x, z in zip(px, position):
    if (px.index(x) > 0): 
        if position[px.index(x)-1] == 0 and position[px.index(x)] == 1: <-- PROBLEM HERE?
            long_position.append(x)

print(long_position)
```

My logic is that if the previous element in the list is 0 and the current element is 1, the program should go long at the corresponding price. This is simply to prevent it from going long when it's already long.

Nevertheless, when I run this, it doesn't append anything in the long_position.

**Can anyone guide me as to what might be going wrong? Any comments on the code will also be greatly appreciated!**

*Basically below is what I'm trying to do:*

```
price  signal long_position

0.6901  Long    0.6901
0.6861  Close   
0.6912  Long    0.6912
0.6898  Long    
0.6866  Close   
0.6885  Long    0.6885
0.6929  Long    
0.6943  Long    
0.7084  Long    
0.7007  Long    
0.7104  Long    
0.7104  Long    
0.7195  Long    
0.7136  Long    
0.7225  Long    
0.7342  Long    
0.7277  Long    
0.7318  Long    
0.7262  Close   
0.7259  Close   
0.7280  Long    0.7280
0.7422  Long    
0.7369  Long    
0.7286  Close   
0.7306  Close   
0.7415  Long    0.7415
```

Comment: Why not numpy for something like this? Also, can you provide some data sample for which, the expected output is what you've shown?

Comment: This might not be your specific problem, but `index` will find the first occurrence of that element - so if your list contains repeats you will get unexpected results. Better to use `enumerate` and then use that -1 for the previous element.

Comment: You're also not using `z` at all in that loop...

Comment: Thanks guys! @match, I was able to solve it using enumerate and tweaking the way I was generating the signal. Pasted the solution above.

Comment: [You can answer your own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**:

Was able to solve the problem using `enumerate` and `index`. Also tweaked the way I was generating the signal. Solved loop below:

```
for index,(x,z) in enumerate(zip(px,position)):
    if index > 0:
        if ((position[index]) + (position[index-1])) == '10':    # for long
            long_position.append(x*-1)
        elif ((position[index]) + (position[index-1])) == '01':  # for close
            close_position.append(x)
        else:
            pass
```

Thanks for the help, guys!